# why more command is not take stdin for reading input?

Tags: c, linux, exec, dup2

In more command, it does not read the input from the stdin. But using dup2() function change stdin as a one file descriptors that time it will work. why it is doing like this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
main()
   {
   int fd=open("coprocess.c",O_RDWR);

    if ( fork() ==  0 ) 
    { 
    dup2(fd,0);
    close(fd);
    execl("/bin/more","more",(char *)0);
    printf("error\n");
    }
    else 
    wait(0);
```

}

Comment: Obviously more is reading from stdin, otherwise your sample with dup2 would not work!?

Answer (score 0):

'more' can read from stdin or from a file given on the command line.  It looks like in the case that the file path was given on the command line, 'more' opens that file and re-exec's itself, setting the open file descriptor to stdin.

In doing this, the core of the implementation of 'more' is always reading from stdin.